# How should I add a geojson in URL for static image api?

Tags: python, mapbox, geojson

I have this geojson (all this code is in python)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties":  {
        "stroke": "#000000",
        "fill": "#005776",
        "fill-opacity": 1.0
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-81.26581704096897, 28.37974376331988],
            [-81.26601725837781, 28.37977498699149],
            [-81.26613780689904, 28.37940694447166],
            [-81.26594365491499, 28.3793572200485],
            [-81.26581704096897, 28.37974376331988]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am encoding it like this:

```
geojson_string = json.dumps(geojson, separators=(',', ':'))
geojson_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(f"{{{geojson_string}}}")
```

And getting this string:

```
%7B%22type%22%3A%22FeatureCollection%22%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22Feature%22%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%22stroke%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C%22fill%22%3A%22%23005776%22%2C%22fill-opacity%22%3A1%7D%2C%22geometry%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Polygon%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B%5B%5B-81.26581704096897%2C28.37974376331988%5D%2C%5B-81.26601725837781%2C28.37977498699149%5D%2C%5B-81.26613780689904%2C28.37940694447166%5D%2C%5B-81.26594365491499%2C28.3793572200485%5D%2C%5B-81.26581704096897%2C28.37974376331988%5D%5D%5D%7D%7D%7D
```

Then I am making the url like this:

```
url = f"https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{user}/{style}/static/geojson(geojson_encoded)/auto/640x360?{access_token}"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
message: "Failed parsing geojson"
```

Can someone help me to know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to lie with how your Python code is encoding and/or making the request against the API, so I would recommend you double check that the request being made is what you expect it to be.

If I take your unencoded geojson object, and include it directly within a cURL request (making sure to encode just the necessary forbidden use of `#` for colors), then I don't have any issues receiving a valid response:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/static/geojson({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"stroke":"%23000000","fill":"%23005776","fill-opacity":1},"geometry":{"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[-81.26581704096897,28.37974376331988],[-81.26601725837781,28.37977498699149],[-81.26613780689904,28.37940694447166],[-81.26594365491499,28.3793572200485],[-81.26581704096897,28.37974376331988]]]}}]})/auto/630x360?access_token=my.token
```

The above request responds with your desired image (albeit, without the custom user style):

[image: static map image with polygon in center]

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: can we pass the link of our geojson with static map like we do for custom marker as our path is much more lenghty

Comment: @ParthDhorda currently 3rd party GeoJson is not supported. However, if you're running into issues with uri length, you might consider uploading your GeoJSON data as a tileset and adding it to your map using the `addlayer` style parameter instead: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/static-images-style-params/